# Is it possible to test Discuss action in android Pepper Robot emulator

Tags: java, android, pepper

I was trying to create a pepper robot app which interact with human. And followed the documentation [link](https://android.aldebaran.com/sdk/doc/pepper-sdk/tutorials/discuss_tutorial.html#discuss-tutorial)

The code executed without any error but the robot is not detecting the human voice. Please tell me whether it is possible to test Discuss  action(Listen and reply) in emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is possible, Follow the same link which you have shared and in the Robot viewer goto->Dialog view-> at the bottom there is a space to enter the human input(Emulator won't detect the user voice).

Please find the image for reference [Emulator image(Robo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZthH.png)